# Callback routine in Android

Tags: android

I ran into a piece of Android code. I don't quite understand the purpose of the callback because it's empty.

In Animation.java

```
private AnimationCallback callback = null;

public Animation(final AnimationCallback animationCallBack) {
    this();
    callback = animationCallBack;
}

public void stop() {
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onAnimationFinished(this);
    }
    active = false;
}
public interface AnimationCallback { void onAnimationFinished(final Animation animation); }
```

but in `AnimationCallback` there's only

```
public interface AnimationCallback {
    void onAnimationFinished(final Animation animation);
}
```

I guess my question is what does `callback.onAnimationFinished(this)` do? There doesn't seem to have anything inside the routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor is declared to take anything that implements the `AnimationCallback` interface. In Java, an *interface* defines the behavior of an object without specifying any of its behavior.

The actual object that gets passed to the constructor is some concrete class that implements the `AnimationCallback` interface. You'd have to know the actual class of the object being used to know what it does.

Per request, here's a simple (and fairly useless) class that just logs the fact that an animation has finished:

```
public AnimationFinishedLogger implements AnimationCallback {
    public void onAnimationFinished(final Animation animation) {
        Log.i("AnimationLogger", "Animation finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give just brief sample in terms of implements the AnimationCallback?